# replace strings with enums in switch statment

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2008, enums

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and trying to convert this switch statement

```
        switch (salesOrderPayment.PaymentCardKey.ToUpper()) {
            case "MC":
                ValidateCreditCard(salesOrderPayment,errorMessages);
                break;
            case "VISA":
                ValidateCreditCard(salesOrderPayment, errorMessages);
                break;
            case "TELECHECK":
                //ValidateTelecheck(salesOrderPayment, errorMessages);
                ValidateAchCheck(salesOrderPayment, errorMessages);
                break;
            case "ACH":
                ValidateAchCheck(salesOrderPayment, errorMessages);
                break;
```

To use an enum that I have created

```
    public enum PaymentType {
        MC,
        VISA,
        AMEX,
        TELECHECK,
        CASH,
        ACH }
```

I've tried this:

```
switch (Enum.Parse(typeof(PaymentType),salesOrderPayment.PaymentCardKey.ToUpper()))
```

but get red squiggly lines and when I hover over it says "A value of an integral type expected".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
switch ((PaymentType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PaymentType),salesOrderPayment.PaymentCardKey,true)))
```

Notice the cast to `PaymentType` type, also note that your switch cases has to be enum fields rather than strings.

I've used another overload of [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes `bool ignoreCase` as parameter, make use of it so that you don't need `ToUpper` call.

Comment: thanks, I just had to remove on of the right parentheses to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

As the Enum.Parse method returns with an Object (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), you will need to cast the result of `Enum.Parse` to `PaymentType`.